# Aptana Studio 3 as plugin fails to startup on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have installed Eclipse 3.7.2 via PPA and subsequently I have clicked on Add New Software and the link to 64Bit Aptana studio 3.

It found the plugin and installed it correctly.

Now when I startup the Eclipse I get this error:

```
An internal error has occurred.
No more handlesNative code library failed to load. (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /home/xxx/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/plugins/com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.linux.x86_64_1.0.0.1295409059/os/linux/x86_64/libcefjni.so: libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Any idea please?

Update:

Seems to be the Java version:

```
!SESSION 2012-04-30 07:48:06.985 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736
java.version=1.7.0_04
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-04-30 07:48:07.951
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        no swt-gtk-3740 in java.library.path
        no swt-gtk in java.library.path
        Can't load library: /home/xxx/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk-3740.so
        Can't load library: /home/xxx/.swt/lib/linux/x86_64/libswt-gtk.so

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:285)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:21)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here:

http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/

Comment: But this problem remains.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261037/django-on-aptana-studio-3-0

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using aptana as standalone version? I Use aptana every day and there's no conflict at all with my Ubuntu 12.04.

Consider asking in the official Support page:
[Aptana | Support](http://www.aptana.com/support)

Or see if is that is a current bug.

I hope you find a solution (:

Comment: yeah I have tried that and get this error message: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261037/django-on-aptana-studio-3-0 :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10482634/207791

> I had same problem with Oracle Java 7 and Eclipse on 32-bit system.
>
> `libswt-gtk-3.6-java` and `libswt-gtk-3.6-jni` were already installed.
>   [What helped](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swt-gtk/+bug/975560):
>
> ```
> cd ~/.swt/lib/linux/x86
> ln -s /usr/lib/jni/* .
> ```
>
> Maybe this can be done reconfiguring Java alternatives or what.